# Inheritance in Java - Extend only some methods from parent class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a question on Inheritance in Java.  Is it possible to inherit only some of methods from base class that a Sub Class extends?

For example, I have class A which has 10 methods, class B extends A  but I need to inherit only 5(1,2,3,4,5) methods of A, and Class C which also Extended from A.  I need to inherit 3 methods, say (8,9,10), can any one please help me to solve this issue?

If this is possible, please clarify with Code.

Comment: So you're talking about an abstract class with abstract methods and you want to implement (some of) them in your subclasses, not override already implemented methods, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement only certain methods of an abstract class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699898/how-to-implement-only-certain-methods-of-an-abstract-class)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?  Code rather than sentences would help.

Comment: You posted no code, and your terminology is wrong, so it's hard to understand what you want to do. You don't extend methods. You extend a class, implement an interface, and override a method.

Comment: Friends I am not trying...I am just asking is it possible..please read the question clearly

Comment: @JBNizet I am just asking opinion about the logic..is it possible to Extend some of my methods from parent class to Sub class...Are you Understand.?? and code is not necessary

Comment: Problem is we are not able to understand what are you trying to do since there is no such thing as extending method in Java. You can extend class (not method). Things you can do with methods are: inherit, override, overload, invoke (, ...maybe few others which I don't remember now, but not extend).

Comment: @user6427267 feel free not to provide the requested information. But then don't wonder why you get downvotes, close votes, and no satisfying answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no such thing as *method extension*. You can extend a class and *override* or *hide* its methods.

1. [A subclass inherits all of the public and protected members of its parent, no matter what package the subclass is in.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)
2. [An instance method in a subclass with the same signature (name, plus the number and the type of its parameters) and return type as an instance method in the superclass overrides the superclass's method.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)
3. [If a subclass defines a static method with the same signature as a static method in the superclass, then the method in the subclass hides the one in the superclass.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about extends I'm assuming you're not talking about an interface? If so, you can just override the functions.

EDIT: more info as requested. If you extend a class, say:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {}
```

You can just override the methods in Animal. Say Animal has a method called walk:

```
public void walk() { x += 1; }
```

You can override this in the class Dog with:

```
public void walk() { x += 2; }
```

When you now call new Dog().walk() it will call the walk method from the Dog class, not from the Animal class.

Comment: Hi,Are you understood what I am trying to Say.?if so ,please elaborate about override the methods.. Thanks.!

Comment: @user6427267 Hope it's clear now.